# Is "take over on" common/idiomatic?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

A line from the film *Michael Clayton*:

> Barry's taking over **on** U/North. We got a lot of grovelling to do.

Barry is an associate at a law firm, and U/North is a case/client. I would expect *take over* a case/client. Google Books show a limited number of instances of *take over on*, most results false positives. Is "take over on" idiomatic/commonly said? Is **on** here a preposition or part of the whole phrasal verb?

Comment: I understand it as intransitive _take over_, plus _on_ = _about, concerning_. But I had to think about it: I don't think it is idiomatic.

Comment: This does strike me as weird, but keep in mind movies aren't (and shouldn't be) written to be 100% idiomatic, or the actor flubbed her line but they liked the take anyway.

Comment: As a native speaker, it doesn't seem odd at all, but it's very clearly (take over) (on some topic).

Answer (score 15):

You need to consider 'take over' and 'on' separately. The phrasal verb 'take over' has its normal meaning, and (I suspect) the preposition 'on' here is used idiomatically/conversationally to denote assignment to a task or role, and, as you suggest, might be omitted in more formal speech. Consider a random example I just made up: I am head chef in a restaurant kitchen. I have two chefs under me, Pete who is 'on' fish, and Mary, who is 'on' desserts (I put them 'on' these jobs). If I need Mary to do something, I might say 'Mary, please go to the store and get some peppercorns. I'll take over on desserts'.

Answer (score 10):

The preposition **on** is also used with the accounts/customers of a business, such as a PR firm or a law firm:

> Who should we put as lead **on** the Acme Widgets account?

And the account/customer can be referred to by name:

> Who should we put as lead on Acme Widgets?
>   -- Let's put Jim on that account.
>   We can't. Jim's taking over on Spacely Sprockets.

That is, Jim is replacing the current account lead on the Spacely Sprockets account.